# How VS2019 Linux C++ debugger indexes files?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio, c++, debugger, visual-studio-2019

How VS2019 Linux C++ debugger indexes files?

Does Visual Studio 2019 Linux ssh c++ debugger index files for IntelliSense use on Linux server where gdb is or it establishes a SSH connection for each file then make the indexation on a client machine?